# In Microsoft Dynamics 365 F&O why do long names and descriptions cause errors?

Tags: sql-server, runtime-error, microsoft-dynamics, string-length, truncated

I have defined a `Table` called `MedicinesTable` with the following fields:

- MedicineName, Extended Data Type: Name
- MedicineDescription, Extended Data Type: Description

I can see in the Properties, each of these _should have a String Size of 60.

However, when I open the Table in the table browser and then try to insert or update a Medicine with any name of more than 10 characters (i.e. "My medicine 1"), see "The SQL database has issued an error".

More specifically, I also see "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated."

Why does more than 10 characters for either of these fields result in errors like this?
How do I fix it?

Comment: The error says that the database column is too short. Instead of a length of 60, it's 10. We can't guess how that table and column were created. There's no `Name` or `Description` type in SQL Server. The text types are `char(n)` and `varchar(n)` for single-codepage text, `nchar(n)` and `nvarchar(n)` for Unicode

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I can't tell you how D365F&O created these fields, but I can tell you how _I_ created them in D365.  1. I opened VS2017; 2. I created a project ("D365Stuff"); 3. I added a new item of type "Table" with the name "MedinesTable"; 4. I created the fields on the table with the names and EDTs specified above; 5. I told VS2017 to synchronize the database; and 6. I told VS2017 to build the project.

Comment: @Panagiotis_Kanavos *name* and *description* can be SQL DOMAINs (aka TYPE in SQL Server)...